# Авторизация на Laravel через сторонние API

Tags: php, laravel

Есть сайт на Laravel, и есть API, которые расположены на другом сервере, они выполняют все функции ЛК от регистрации до пополнения баланса и прочими фичами.

Как мне на моём сайте хранить авторизованного пользователя? и не пускать гостей на страницы, которым гостям нельзя?

API мне будет возвращать token сессии при авторизации. Планирую его хранить в сессии и стучать по методам с этим токеном.

ps. на моём сайте бд не будет и не планируется.

Comment: токены можно хранить в сессии, а список доступных страниц(меню) брать по АПи с сервера

Comment: Добавьте middleware (прокладку), и через неё делайте проверку на данные в сессии пользователя аналогично уже существующей прокладке по авторизации. Затем добавьте вашу прокладку в пути (routes), которые доступны только “токенизированным” пользователям.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov где подробнее можно почитать об этом? мне понравился ход Ваших мыслей.

Comment: @sbaikov на официальном сайте Laravel - [создание прокладки](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware) и [защита пути с её помощью](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes)